# Windowbuilder help- adding components to a new frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, windowbuilder

Hey guys I'm quite new to windowbuilder and in the process of learning how to use it. My question is: how do I add stuff (labels, buttons etc) to a JFrame that has been created when the user chooses an option (ie: create new window).

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) My advice would be to abandon the automagic window builder until you understand how to write the code. Until that time, a builder is holding you back.

Comment: Thanks for your comment !  
Are you saying that I should manually create a new JFrame and add things to this ? if you have any pointers that would help !

Comment: No, I'm saying 1) there should **only be one** frame per application & 2) whatever is used in its place should be hand coded. *"if you have any pointers that would help"* [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: Thank you so much !